# PHP Image Magician image not resizing properly

Tags: php, image

So I was adding some image upload functionality to my website and I decided to go with the [PHP Image Magician Library by Jarrod Oberto](http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/wiki-single.html)

Resizing a 1080 pixel wide image to 480 pixels works like a charm. However resizing the image to 720 pixels results in an unexpected crop.

Whatever shall I do to make the 720 pixel image resize perfectly?

The code Im using for he resize is;

```
    <?php
    $magicianObj = new imageLib("original.jpg");
    $magicianObj -> resizeImage(480, 800);
    $magicianObj -> saveImage("480.jpg", 100);
    $magicianObj -> resizeImage(720, 1280);
    $magicianObj -> saveImage("720.jpg", 100);
```

Here are the images:

1. 480 pixels

[image: 480 pixels]

2. 720 pixels

[image]

Comment: Does it make any difference if you resize firstly to 720 and save it then resize to 480 and save?

Comment: Lemme try your suggestion and tell you

Comment: So now the 480 pixel image is messed up. But I know how to fix it. Thanks. Add it as an answer and Ill thumbs up it.

Comment: and the 720px - is that now fine or also snafu?

Comment: Add What you said on your first comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it make any difference if you resize firstly to 720 and save it then resize to 480 and save?

```
$magicianObj = new imageLib("original.jpg");
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(720, 1280);
$magicianObj -> saveImage("720.jpg", 100);

$magicianObj -> resizeImage(480, 800);
$magicianObj -> saveImage("480.jpg", 100);
```